# How to refer custom partition grouper in my Kafka stream application?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Customized grouping Tasks by topic name instead of partition Id.

How to refer my custom partition grouper class in my Kafka stream application ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't understand the question. Btw: it's not recommended to write a custom partition grouper. There are many dependencies and assumptions and if you are not familiar with the internals of Kafka Streams, you most likely would not write a correct partitioner but break Kafka Streams by using your custom partitioner.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom partition grouper class using the `StreamsConfig.PARTITION_GROUPER_CLASS_CONFIG` option in your streams config.

However, as Matthias says, this is unadvisable unless you know what you're doing or want to learn :). Perhaps what you are trying to do can be accomplished some other way?

Answer (score 0):

As a result of a bug in Kafka-Streams source code (version 2.1.0), you'll need in addition to add this configuration with a consumer prefix as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(PARTITION_GROUPER_CLASS_CONFIG), CustomPartitionGrouper.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.PARTITION_GROUPER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomPartitionGrouper.class.getName());
```

The reason for adding the consumer config prefix is that the `StickyTaskAssignor` and the `PartitionGrouper` instances are being initialized in the consumer initialization flow. Without the prefix, the consumer will ignore the `PARTITION_GROUPER_CLASS_CONFIG` and will use the default which is the `DefaultPartitionGrouper` class.